# Can't get the background full width

Tags: css, background-color

Please see this site http://www.lovinmybags.co/
The Primary Menu have full width background with this code

```
#PrimaryMenu > ul > li.ActivePage > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font: normal 0.80em Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But when I use the same code for #FooterMenu, the bacground is rather small. And the background for Products page is not active.May anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `a` element in `#FooterMenu` the follow CSS rule:

```
#FooterMenu > ul > li.ActivePage > a { 
   padding: 13px;
   margin: 0;
}
```

The `padding-top` value could be 14px too. You choose.

If you want to see the Products item active when you visit the Products page you only have to add `.ActivePage` to the `li` element. See the below code:

```
<!-- The rest of your content -->
    <li class="HasSubMenu ActivePage">
     <a href="/categories.php"><span>Products</span></a>
<!-- The rest of your content -->
```

**Be careful, you must to add the `.ActivePage` class to the `li` inside the #FooterMenu element!**

Cheers,
Leonardo

Comment: It full heigh now, but the width is still not ok, how to make it wider?

Comment: As I put in my post, you have to set the `margin` to 0.

Comment: And what about the background of Products page? It disappear.

Comment: What's the Products page? Did you mean the "categories"? If that is, what's wrong with the background?

Comment: You can see at this page http://www.lovinmybags.co/categories.php
The activepage background is disappear. That is the theme problem?

Comment: Ok it done now, thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

```
#PrimaryMenu > ul > li.ActivePage > a:hover {
color: #ffffff;
font: normal 0.80em Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #222222;
font-weight: bold;
padding-bottom: 13px; /*New*/

}
```